# What is Community Cloud in Salesforce? Why we use it?

Tags: community

Any reference how we can start learning community cloud.

Answer (score 3):

From trailhead, Community Cloud is:

> At its most basic level, a community is a group of people who share a common mission or goal. You can define what collaboration model best fits your needs. Do you want to have customers helping one another out? Peer-to-peer communities do just that. Perhaps you want a portal, where your customers can, for example, access account information.
>
> Maybe you want to use a community to generate ideas for new products. Or test prototypes in a safe space, log support tickets, provide live chat with agents, or sell products. All these business processes—and more—can come to life in an online community.

Community plays a handy role specially with new templates which they've introduced. Give it shot.

Best way to start: [Get Started with Community Cloud](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/community_cloud_basics/units/communities_intro_to_community_cloud) trailhead